# LogParser: SQL table column "X" data type is not compatible with SELECT clause item "cs-username" (type STRING)

Tags: sql-server, iis, logparser

I'm trying to use [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) to insert relevant rows from IIS logfiles into a SQL-Server table.

I created my table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.WebLog (Id INT IDENTITY, UserName VARCHAR(MAX),
    URL VARCHAR(MAX), DateStampUTC DATETIME)
```

This is how I'm calling LogParser:

```
LogParser "SELECT cs-username, cs-uri-stem, TO_TIMESTAMP(date,time) 
INTO WebLog FROM ex*.log 
WHERE cs-uri-stem IN ('urlsThatICareAbout.html') AND cs-username IS NOT NULL" 
-server:<server> 
-database:<database>
-username:<username> 
-password:<password> 
-transactionRowCount:-1 
-ignoreIdCols:ON 
-o:SQL 
-driver:"SQL Server" 
-i:IISW3C
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
SQL table column "UserName" data type is not compatible with
    SELECT clause item "cs-username" (type STRING)
```

Any ideas? Are types STRING and VARCHAR(MAX) incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to reduce that to something like NVARCHAR(1000) or even 255 or less.  VARCHAR(max) is seen as a TEXT/BLOB type by some older libraries.  It could also be the difference between VARCHAR and NVARCHAR (for international characters)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the native SQL Server driver and not defaulting to the SQL Server ODBC driver -- that has always worked for me.

```
LogParser "SELECT cs-username, cs-uri-stem, TO_TIMESTAMP(date,time) 
INTO WebLog FROM ex*.log 
WHERE cs-uri-stem IN ('urlsThatICareAbout.html') AND cs-username IS NOT NULL" 
-server:<server> 
-database:<database>
-username:<username> 
-password:<password> 
-transactionRowCount:-1 
-ignoreIdCols:ON 
-o:SQL 
-driver:"SQL Server Native Client 10.0" 
-i:IISW3C
```